# Is there any initiative to start a community about sports?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if a community for people who play any sport will be worth. Is there any initiative?

Comment: http://sports.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: You should ask questions like this over on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Sports**](https://sports.stackexchange.com) is currently in public beta. You can join the beta right now, and find out more about the site on [its Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports).